# Changing a ConnectionString

Tags: c#

I have a Win Form with a text box called Location_txtBx and a browse button which runs an OpenFileDialog which passes the file selected to the textbox Location_txtBx which on the TextChanged event passes the text to a string called Con. Is there a way to change the source part of a connectionString so that an admin can change the database location?

Comment: Yes is the answer... but we will need more details to let you know how in your specific context...

Comment: Well there's [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx), assuming it's SQL Server. Or it's just a string you can manipulate if you want.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Try to create reproducible problem statement.
 [mcve]

Comment: Sorry I should of said its an Access database simply called database2. I tried concatenating the string to make it easier but Visual studio complains about all the ". What I was trying to do was create a string like @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Documents\Database2.accdb;
Persist Security Info=False;";
Where source equals whatever text gets put in the textbox Location_txtBx 
and after that by pressing a button it gets used as the new ConnectionString by using some method to pass it to a file which gets read by all the other forms

Answer (score 0):

I have now added a Button called Acceptbtn and on the on click event given it the code.

```
if (File.Exists("D:\\Connect.file"))
{
    File.Delete("D:\\Connect.file");
}
string provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=";
string Security = ";Persist Security Info=False;";

string con = provider + Location_txtBx.Text + Security;
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("D:\\Connect.file");
sw.WriteLine(con);
sw.Close();
Location_txtBx.Text = "";
Acceptbtn.Enabled = false;
```

and I used in each form the code

```
string connect = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("D:\\Connect.file");
connection.ConnectionString = connect;
```

This work and outputs the connection string to the renamed text file Connect.file. But this seems rather insecure.